# How to print one Attribute in a class in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, class, attributes, class-attributes

simply i have a class that has a method to print a specific attibute in a class example:

```py
class Attr:
    def __init__(self, name,
     wattage):
        self.name = name
        self.wattage = wattage
   
    def print_attr(self):
        print("attribute in class is " + getattr(Attr, wattage)
```

the expected output is:

```py
attribute name is wattage: test
```

Comment: `print("attribute in class is " + getattr(self, "wattage"))`

Comment: Curious, why not `self.wattage` directly?

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a helper function for this, Python does not have restricted access. Simply access the attribute directly:

```py
a = Attr("Name", 10)

print(a.wattage)
```

If you truly want to make a print method like this, there are two ways to do it:

```py
class Attr:
    def __init__(self, name, wattage):
        self.name = name
        self.wattage = wattage
   
    def print_wattage(self):
        print(f'Wattage in *instance* is {getattr(self, "wattage")}')  # getattr gets by string name

    def print_name(self):
        print(f"Name in *instance* is {self.name}")
```